# Crear una secuencia a partir de un campo Oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo una tabla con varios registros que tomo de una consulta(primera consulta) select y al tomar los datos se insertan en otra tabla. Para esto tomo un dato del select para que se inserten.Esta tabla tiene una secuencia para IDEXPEDIENTE y tiene llaves primaria compuestas que es esta y el de RUTADOC.

Bien como muestro en la imagen el numero de expediente para 6 registros me muestra diferente, así es como busco que quede. Solo que al consultar por otro dato master tengo mas registros pero con diferentes house , si consulto por master me salen 60 registros con 6 house diferentes yo busco que cuando el dato de house cambia este numero de idexpediente cambie porque si tomo master todos me los registra con mismo idexpediente.

Los datos que se recuperan de la primera base de datos .
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo mi consulta
---Procedimiento para extraer la información de una tabla y insertarla a otra

```
PROCEDURE Sp_ConsultaInsertarDatos(pfld2 VARCHAR2, pfld3 VARCHAR2, pfld1 VARCHAR2, saldatos_cursor  OUT datos_cursor) IS
                            
   sal_cursor datos_cursor;   
   fechaActual DATE;     
   --FST136_RUTADOC varchar(40 byte);
   --FST136_GHOUSE varchar(40 byte);
   Sec_FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE varchar2(25 byte) ;    
    
    BEGIN
       
        SELECT sysdate into fechaActual from dual;       
        --Secuencia para ir incrementando los Ids
        SELECT 'EXP-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMM') || TRIM(TO_CHAR(SEC_GUIAINVESDOC.NEXTVAL, '9999999999')) INTO Sec_FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE FROM DUAL; 
        --COMMIT;
                                                                                   
    DECLARE
                                                    
            CURSOR c_ConsultaDatos IS 
            SELECT ''  Fst136_IdExpediente, rinves11.IVOLREPHDR.name TIPO, fld2 MASTER, fld3 HOUSE, rinves11.A20SF.fld1 REGISTRO, 
            dbms_lob.substr@INVESDOC((SELECT replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(rinves11.IVOLREPHDR.info, '"01.01"|"\\Srv-invest', '\192.170.1.103'),'"01.01"|"\\srv-invest','\192.170.1.103'),'"01.01"|"\',''),'"01.01"|"\\192.170.1.104',''),'"01.01"|"',''),'"|3|1|3|0|0',''),'"|3|2|3|0|0','') || '\' || rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR.name || '\' || rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR.loc 
            FROM dual@INVESDOC), 4000, 1) AS INFO
            FROM rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR@INVESDOC 
            INNER JOIN rinves11.A20SF@INVESDOC  ON rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR.extid2 = rinves11.A20SF.fdrid
            INNER JOIN rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR@INVESDOC  ON rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR.volid  = rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR.id
            INNER JOIN rinves11.IVOLREPHDR@INVESDOC  ON rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR.repid = rinves11.IVOLREPHDR.id
            WHERE fld2 = NVL(pfld2,fld2) AND fld3 = NVL(pfld3, fld3) AND  fld1 = NVL(pfld1, fld1);
        
        --BEGIN     
           --IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT FST136_GHOUSE, FST136_RUTADOC from FST136_GUIASINVESDOC where FST136_RUTADOC=r_Columna.INFO)         
    BEGIN       
    
       FOR r_Columna IN c_ConsultaDatos LOOP 
       
       --IF (FST136_RUTADOC > 0) AND (FST136_GHOUSE > 0) THEN
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ya se encuentra registrado');
       --END IF;
       
       INSERT INTO FST136_GUIASINVESDOC(FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE,FST136_NAMETIPOEXPEDIENTE, FST136_GMASTER,FST136_GHOUSE,FST136_REGISTRO,FST136_RUTADOC)
       VALUES (Sec_FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE ,r_Columna.TIPO , r_Columna.MASTER,r_Columna.HOUSE,r_Columna.REGISTRO,r_Columna.INFO);
       --COMMIT;
       END LOOP;
        
    COMMIT;
       
         
    OPEN sal_cursor FOR
    
    SELECT FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE,FST136_NAMETIPOEXPEDIENTE, FST136_GMASTER,FST136_GHOUSE,FST136_REGISTRO,FST136_RUTADOC
    FROM  FST136_GUIASINVESDOC
    WHERE FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE = Sec_FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE;
    saldatos_cursor := sal_cursor; 

    END;
    
      

END Sp_ConsultaInsertarDatos;
```

Y esta es mi tabla como debería quedar con numero de expediente diferente(se que son los mismos datos pero aun estoy en pruebas).Espero puedan orientarme de antemano gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, disculpa; no entiendo cuál es el problema que quieres resolver aquí

Comment: volvi a describir lo que pregunto, espero ahora si este entendible, si no me puede comentar nuevamente se lo agradeceria

Comment: UN poco más, pero todo va a tener sentido si incluyes una muestra breve de los datos de origen, así ver qué es lo que quieres representar como muestras en la imagen

Comment: ya la añadi esa no tiene idexpediente yo lo agrego en el insert con la secuencia